# php javabridge execution command line

Tags: java, php, tomcat7, php-java-bridge

I have installed javabridge on tomcat 7
 and it works well on the browser while entring the url (localhost:8080/JavaBridgeTemplate621/myscript.php).
I want to execute my php script on a command line 
so I tried

> cd C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin //(the path oftomcat 7.exe)
>   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin> php  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\JavaBridgeTemplate621\myscript.php

==> it show me :Could not open open C:\program

Comment: php "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\JavaBridgeTemplate621\myscript.php"

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the path because of the spaces:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin" //(the path oftomcat 7.exe)
php "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\JavaBridgeTemplate621\myscript.php"
```

Comment: could not open input file:C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\JavaBridgeTemplate621\myscript.php

Comment: Well either your script is not there or you don't have the permission to read it. Can you be more specific on the error?

Comment: hw to change permission?, my script works well from the browser

Comment: I'm executing cmd with admin privilege

Comment: Witout more information on the error I will not be able to help you, sorry.